# QWT installation errors

Tags: c++, qt, installation, nmake, qwt

I started using Qt a few weeks ago and I am really enjoying it. I now need to include graphs in my application and, after some research, I found that Qwt was the best way of doing so (rather than having to do everything from scratch by myself). I've been at it for a couple of days, and I can't figure out how to install it. I am using windows7 32 bit. I followed the instructions in the INSTALL file:

from cmd ->

```
qmake qwt.pro
nmake
```

after nmake finishes I am left with errors

```
C:\Users\Peyo\Downloads\qwt-6.0.1>qmake qwt.pro

C:\Users\Peyo\Downloads\qwt-6.0.1>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd src\ && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.e
xe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Make
file.Debug all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

moc qwt_dyngrid_layout.h
moc qwt_magnifier.h
moc qwt_panner.h
moc qwt_picker.h
moc qwt_text_label.h
moc qwt_legend.h
moc qwt_legend_item.h
moc qwt_plot.h
moc qwt_plot_renderer.h
moc qwt_plot_canvas.h
moc qwt_plot_panner.h
moc qwt_plot_picker.h
moc qwt_plot_zoomer.h
moc qwt_plot_magnifier.h
moc qwt_sampling_thread.h
moc qwt_scale_widget.h
moc qwt_abstract_slider.h
moc qwt_analog_clock.h
moc qwt_compass.h
moc qwt_counter.h
moc qwt_dial.h
moc qwt_knob.h
moc qwt_slider.h
moc qwt_thermo.h
moc qwt_wheel.h
compiling .\qwt_abstract_scale_draw.cpp .\qwt_interval_symbol.cpp .\qwt_clipper.
cpp .\qwt_color_map.cpp .\qwt_column_symbol.cpp .\qwt_interval.cpp .\qwt_dyngrid
_layout.cpp .\qwt_math.cpp .\qwt_magnifier.cpp .\qwt_panner.cpp .\qwt_null_paint
device.cpp .\qwt_painter.cpp .\qwt_picker.cpp .\qwt_round_scale_draw.cpp .\qwt_s
cale_div.cpp .\qwt_scale_draw.cpp .\qwt_scale_map.cpp .\qwt_spline.cpp .\qwt_tex
t_engine.cpp .\qwt_text_label.cpp .\qwt_text.cpp .\qwt_event_pattern.cpp .\qwt_p
icker_machine.cpp .\qwt_point_3d.cpp .\qwt_point_polar.cpp .\qwt_scale_engine.cp
p .\qwt_symbol.cpp .\qwt_system_clock.cpp .\qwt_curve_fitter.cpp .\qwt_legend.cp
p .\qwt_legend_item.cpp .\qwt_plot.cpp .\qwt_plot_renderer.cpp .\qwt_plot_xml.cp
p .\qwt_plot_axis.cpp .\qwt_plot_curve.cpp .\qwt_plot_dict.cpp .\qwt_plot_direct
painter.cpp .\qwt_plot_grid.cpp .\qwt_plot_histogram.cpp .\qwt_plot_item.cpp .\q
wt_plot_intervalcurve.cpp .\qwt_plot_spectrogram.cpp .\qwt_plot_spectrocurve.cpp
 .\qwt_plot_scaleitem.cpp .\qwt_plot_seriesitem.cpp .\qwt_plot_marker.cpp .\qwt_
plot_layout.cpp .\qwt_plot_canvas.cpp .\qwt_plot_panner.cpp .\qwt_plot_rasterite
m.cpp .\qwt_plot_picker.cpp .\qwt_plot_zoomer.cpp .\qwt_plot_magnifier.cpp .\qwt
_plot_rescaler.cpp .\qwt_raster_data.cpp .\qwt_matrix_raster_data.cpp .\qwt_samp
ling_thread.cpp .\qwt_series_data.cpp .\qwt_scale_widget.cpp .\qwt_plot_svgitem.
cpp .\qwt_abstract_slider.cpp .\qwt_abstract_scale.cpp .\qwt_arrow_button.cpp .\
qwt_analog_clock.cpp .\qwt_compass.cpp .\qwt_compass_rose.cpp .\qwt_counter.cpp
.\qwt_dial.cpp .\qwt_dial_needle.cpp .\qwt_double_range.cpp .\qwt_knob.cpp .\qwt
_slider.cpp .\qwt_thermo.cpp .\qwt_wheel.cpp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bi
n\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

there are three errors:

```
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0xc0000135'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bi
    n\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
```

And I can't figure out how to solved them. Please help! If I am missing any details, let me know and I'll add them. Thanks!

Comment: did you run your commands from Visual Studio command prompt ? From Qt command prompt ?

Comment: from windows command propmt, but my path is set with everything

Comment: Error 0xc0000135 is STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND. Maybe you need to install another runtime? Try running it with [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to figure out what it's missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running this from Visual Studio command prompt, it set special vcvars stuff you don't have when running in windows command prompt

Comment: I am having same problem..please help

Comment: Did you try to run the installation process from Visual Studio command prompt (not Windows command prompt) ?

Comment: Yes I did..and fix the error..there were some bugs in the older version..thanks.

Comment: One of my problems is also this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667339/install-qwt-on-win7-64bit). I get it, if I install MSVC 2010 and run the nmake from there with the commandprompt from the Qt-installation (which is 2012 by the way), I gat x86-x64 error (because I try installation on 64-bit win7), if I run with the consol from the 2010MCSV. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Better used mingw32-make instead of nmake.

It should work.

I hope your problem will be solved.